# How do I dynamically check to see if a remote font-icon exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using these [Devicon font icons](http://devicon.fr/) for various programming languages.

They don't have every icon, but they have most.

What I want to do is to have a default icon I use for the languages that this font library does not support.

These are their instructions:

```
<!-- in your header -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konpa/devicon/master/devicon.min.css">

<!-- in your body -->
<i class="devicon-ruby-plain"></i>
```

So in my view, I have this:

```
        <div class="vote-icon">
          <i class="devicon-<%= question.language %>-plain"></i>
        </div>
```

Where `question.language` is a user-submitted language on their question.

Right now, when this generates a non-existent icon it just leaves a blank space there.

But I am not quite sure how to check to see if the icon exists, before replacing it with a default.

Thoughts?

Comment: from where `question.language` come from?

Comment: My local db. I am using a syntax highlighter (Rouge) and it provides a Lexer with a library of languages it supports. Whenever the user creates a question, they get to choose a language from that pretty extensive list.

Comment: did you add fonts in your assets?

Comment: Yes, it shows up for other languages. So it works. Its just not all languages are supported in the icon library.

Comment: i think you need to do some jquery stuff ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the only way for me to actually do this is to parse the list of icons available from Devicons.

So I manually created a list in an array in a helper method and then did the nil checks in there.

So it looks like this:

```
  def language_icon(language)
    devicons = ["amazonwebservices", "android", "angularjs", "apache", "appcelerator", "apple", "atom", "backbonejs",
      "bitbucket", "bootstrap", "bower", "c", "chrome", "codeigniter", "coffeescript", "confluence", "cplusplus", "csharp",
      "css3", "d3js", "debian", "django", "docker", "doctrine", "dot-net", "drupal", "erlang", "firefox", "foundation", "gimp",
      "git", "github", "gitlab", "go", "grunt", "gulp", "heroku", "html5", "ie10", "illustrator", "inkscape", "java", "javascript",
      "jeet", "jetbrains", "jquery", "krakenjs", "laravel", "less", "linux", "meteor", "mongodb", "moodle", "mysql", "nginx",
      "nodejs", "nodewebkit", "orale", "photoshop", "php", "phpstorm", "postgresql", "python", "rails", "react", "redhat", "redis",
      "ruby", "safari", "sass", "sourcetree", "ssh", "symfony", "travis", "trello", "ubuntu", "vim", "windows8", "wordpress", "yii", "zend"]

    if devicons.include?(language)
      content_tag(:i, "", class: "devicon-#{language}-plain")
    else
      content_tag(:i, "", class: "fa fa-diamond")
    end
  end
```

That works like a charm.

I hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Thanks for posting! This is what I was avoiding though, we have already loaded the font so this is like duplicating a list we already have. Perhaps there's a way to parse the font glyph names. I'll keep looking and come back if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
require 'open-uri'
=> true
f = open("https://cdn.rawgit.com/konpa/devicon/master/devicon.min.css").read
...load entire css file ...
```

then you make a search

```
@icon = f["devicon-css3-plain"]
```

if @icon is nil it mean that icon no longer exist

in you case

```
 @icon = f[question.language]
```

Comment: totally confused how that would apply here. How do I detect that an `<i>` is `nil`?

Comment: something like ` @icon ||= question.language` in your controller and in the view ` <i class="devicon-<%= @icon %>-plain"></i>`

Comment: Ok...I see what you mean. No, you have misinterpreted the question. There will never be a `nil` value in `question.language`. However, there may be a value (say `make`) that comes from `question.language` that does not exist in the list of icons for various programming languages. Right now, it just renders nothing. But I would like to detect that it didn't find an icon and render something else. There is no built in `nil` value or object for me to query, so I am trying to find an alternative way to determine if it is indeed a `nil` value.

Comment: ohhh, i see, maybe you can search in entire css file for class name i.e i think maybe you can make some search in `https://cdn.rawgit.com/konpa/devicon/master/devicon.min.css`

Comment: That's too heavy. I figured it out. Going to add what I did as an answer.